# Can one programatically determine how much memory is being retained due to java reference?

Tags: java

I'm not asking how much memory a single reference takes up. I'm wondering about in the inverse sense of garbage collection.

i.e. given reference X, how much memory is that reference not allowing the garbage collector to free.

can one do this?

Obviously if one can, and if one has a set of references (A B and C) then it's likely that there will be some overlap in memory being retained (i.e. A and B might both have some connection to the same bit of memory), that's ok.

the point would be, to try and figure out why a memory leak is happening.  If one has a program with long lived objects, one can programatically figure out which of these objects is growing and then rinse and repeat on said objects.

so is it possible?

Comment: May be reading Visual VM (or) Jhat code may help you.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the various `xxxMemory()` methods of [`Runtime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) if you were thinking of implementing your own profiler.

Comment: [MemoryMeasurer](http://memory-measurer.googlecode.com) does this.

Comment: thanks Louis Wasserman, that looks great.

Comment: I know you can get an objects real memory address in hotspots using Unsafe... that's a start at least.

Comment: memorymeasurer helped me find a slow leak in my sqlite jdbc library (unsure where I ever got it from, switched to the one from xerial and it has disappeared).  seems to help a lot.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MemoryMeasurer looks interesting, but I think the question is asking about the memory you don't know about - ie; memory is unexpectedly bloated and you're looking for clues why.

VisualVM has a memory profiler that will tell you what kind of object is being retained, which is a good place to start.   I don't know of any tools that reverse this and tell you what objects are retaining them.

Comment: it actually worked very well fro me. I can provide each class with a "printMem" function and iterate over all my objects.  If I have long running functions within objects, I can provide a private print function for them that every so often prints out the data.  Gives me a much better understanding of what's going on.